# duplicate lines given the number of times a target string occurs in that line with sed, awk, etc

Tags: sed, awk

I would like to transform a file in the following way:

input:

```
LOC100132062,LOC100133331   0.37927964653622    0.434306394092769   
ATAD3A,ATAD3B,ATAD3C    14.9379319811031    15.6244071876106    14.2514567745956    
MMP23A,SLC35E2  1.23714660156378    0.99559795831378    1.47869524481378    
.
.
.
```

preferred output:

```
LOC100132062,LOC100133331   0.37927964653622    0.434306394092769
LOC100132062,LOC100133331   0.37927964653622    0.434306394092769
ATAD3A,ATAD3B,ATAD3C    14.9379319811031    15.6244071876106    14.2514567745956
ATAD3A,ATAD3B,ATAD3C    14.9379319811031    15.6244071876106    14.2514567745956
ATAD3A,ATAD3B,ATAD3C    14.9379319811031    15.6244071876106    14.2514567745956
MMP23A,SLC35E2  1.23714660156378    0.99559795831378    1.47869524481378
MMP23A,SLC35E2  1.23714660156378    0.99559795831378    1.47869524481378
```

i.e. for every string (comma here) that occurs in each line, I'd like to count it and then duplicate that same line by that number of occurrences. So in the first line there is one comma, so duplicate once, in the second line there are two commas, so duplicate that line twice, etc.

Ideally the first column would then be the unique strings originally separated by commas but I'd be quite happy with the above as well! There must a simple solution to this but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 3):

One way is print the line once for every comma-delimited field, like so

```
awk -F, '{for (i=0;i<NF;i++) print }' input
```

Comment: +1 for the best solution, but I wonder why you looped from 0 to NF-1 instead of 1 to NF - the latter is much more common...

Comment: @EdMorton old habit from iterating through zero-indexed arrays I guess

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you asked for an intermediate step, when what you want is this:

```
perl -ne 's/(\S++)//;$a=$1;unshift(@b,$1)while s/(\S++)//;print"$_\t@{[pop@b]}\n"for split/,/,$a;@b=()' FILENAME
```

When given this input:

```
LOC100132062,LOC100133331   0.37927964653622    0.434306394092769   
ATAD3A,ATAD3B,ATAD3C    14.9379319811031    15.6244071876106    14.2514567745956    
MMP23A,SLC35E2  1.23714660156378    0.99559795831378    1.47869524481378
```

The following output is produced:

```
LOC100132062    0.37927964653622
LOC100133331    0.434306394092769
ATAD3A  14.9379319811031
ATAD3B  15.6244071876106
ATAD3C  14.2514567745956
MMP23A  1.23714660156378
SLC35E2 0.99559795831378
```

Comment: Note that this code assumes an equal number of names and numbers. Thus in the last line of input, the last number is ignored because it is not thought to have a corresponding name.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{i=gsub(",",",");for (x=0;x<=i;x++) print $0}' x.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the output from Perl, you can use

```
perl -ape 'print $_ x $F[0] =~ y/,//'
```

The translation in scalar context returns the number of occurrences.

If you want to only keep one of the comma separated strings per line, you can change it to

```
perl -ane 's/.*?\s//; for my $s (0 .. $F[0] =~ tr/,//) {print +(split /,/, $F[0])[$s], " $_"}'
```

Comment: That's simply awesome. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'h;:a;G;s/^[^,]*\n//;t;s/^[^,]*,//;ta' file
```

Answer (score 0):

One more using Perl:

```
perl -F"," -ane 'print $_ x @F;' file
```